# Opencv VideoWriter saves only one frame

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to create 1fps webm from two images,
Code:

```
    // path to output
    string outputVideoPath = "/home/gio/Desktop/giffer/def.webm";
    // write dimensions in size struct
    Size dims = Size(640,480);

    // create and open VideoWriter object
    VideoWriter outputVideo;
    outputVideo.open(outputVideoPath, CV_FOURCC('V','P','8', '0'), 1, dims, true);

    // check if opened
    if(!outputVideo.isOpened()){
        cout << "Creating outputVideo fail" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // I hate strings
    string paths[2];
    paths[0] = "/home/gio/Desktop/giffer/images_temp/g0.jpg";
    paths[1] = "/home/gio/Desktop/giffer/images_temp/g1.jpg";

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        cout << paths[i] << endl;
        Mat temp = imread(paths[i]);
        outputVideo.write(temp);
        usleep(10000);
    }
```

The result is the only frame (last image), 1 seconds long.
What am i doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
I tried on `.avi` extension, `DIVX` codec and it worked. Any ideas how to make it work on `.webm`? or `.gif`

Comment: Why do you hate strings? :D

Comment: Why do you need `usleep(...)`? You already set the fps in the constructor. Try `outputVideo.write(temp.clone());` just to be sure...

Comment: usleep is for being sure too. clone didn't work.

Comment: The same happen to me. It works from 3fps but not with 1 or 2 fps...

Comment: Doesn't work on 3fps or higher either

Comment: I tried on `.avi` extension, `DIVX` codec and it worked. Any ideas how to make it work on `.webm`? or `.gif`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
usleep(1000000);
```

Since `usleep` parameter is given in microseconds, as you [can read here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep).